# issue in Manage scrolling in tab menu in html

Tags: jquery, html, window, scroll

I designed my application using Three tabs.I coded like if a tab contains data more than window size, If user scroll the page, the three tabs is fixed it wont get scrolled. only data will be scrolled. In this what is my problem is if i try to scroll down a tab. It is affecting all the tabs.
This is the Jquery code i used for scrolling

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    // Get the position of the location where the scroller starts.
    var scroller_anchor = $(".scroller_anchor").offset().top;
    // Check if the user has scrolled and the current position is after the scroller's start location and if its not already fixed at the top 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') !=  'fixed') {
        // Change the CSS of the scroller to hilight it and fix it at the top of the screen.
        $('.scroller').css({
            'background': '#FFF',
            'border': '0px solid #000',
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0px'
        });
        // Changing the height of the scroller anchor to that of scroller so that there is no change in the overall height of the page.
        $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '50px');
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'relative') {
        // If the user has scrolled back to the location above the scroller anchor place it back into the content.
        // Change the height of the scroller anchor to 0 and now we will be adding the scroller back to the content.
        $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '0px');

        // Change the CSS and put it back to its original position.
        $('.scroller').css({
            'background': '#FFF',
            'border': '0px solid #CCC',
            'position': 'relative'
        });
    }
});
```

Please help me. If user scroll one tab another should be in its actual position. It shouldnt be in scrolled position.. Any one help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be easier for us to test with your HTML DOM directly, could you please provide it ?
And CSS too, if possible ?

Comment: sorry . Its not possible. i used many css libraries and js libraries to designed my page. So its difficult to provide all those stuff. Can you please tell me the idea how i it can be  fixed?

Comment: So just the rendered HTML part, maybe ? Or do you have an online public version ?

Comment: I got solution.But don't know how to implement in jquery. What will be the function? Those things i don't know. I ll tell you what i is my solution. Each time i click tab to view corresponding tab data. So i need to reset the tab div to actual position. So i need to write the code in click event on that tab. But i dont know what ll be the code and all. Please help me

Comment: Sorry it is under Coding phase. Not in deployment phase.

Comment: Please do needful with my idea if you think it will workout

Comment: If you have any issues in understanding my issue. please let me know. I ll explain in detail.. Please do needful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, my problem is that I do not understand your problem, and without testing I cannot visualise...
Could you set up a JSFiddle maybe ? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I ll tell your clearly.I designed a page which contain three tabs which is fixed in top. If user scroll the scroll bar in browser window when tab content exceed the page, the tabs that are in top never scrolled. Because i made it as fixed. if user clicking a tab and it has more content than window,he scroll to see the rest of the content. Now user click second tab for viewing second tab content it shouldn't already scrolled one. My problem is this only. If i click first tab and scrolled then all other tab data is in scrolled state not in its actual state.

Comment: Thanks first for taking my issue. Still you cant understand my issue let me know. I ll do something

Comment: Okay, if I understand your problem, you would like to reset the scrolling state of other tabs when you click on one new tab, isn't it ?

If this is not your problem, could you even take some screenshots and send it to me ?

(Please edit your comments instead of adding more than one)

Comment: Perfect dude. That is my problem. Please help me to solve my problem..Thank you for understood my problem. Please provide solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion comments, it appears you have to bind a click on a new tab, to reset the scrolling state of other tabs, maybe in a way like this ?

```
var resetScrollingStateOnOtherTabs = function () {
    $('.tabs:not(.active)').css({
        // [...]
    });
}

$('.tabs').on('click', function (e) {
    // Add a class to the clicked tab
    // ONLY IF THERE IS NOT ALREADY ONE !
    // The goal of this is only to separate the CSS rules...
    $('.tabs').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active').css({
        // [...]
    });
    resetScrollingStateOnOtherTabs();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. What i have to write it in the css part dude

Comment: If I understand your problem, yes it is !

This sample just bind a click on a ".tabs" element, add an "active" class to the clicked one and allow you to apply CSS both in the newly "active" element, but also different rules in all the other ".tabs" elements.

Of course it would be cleaner to write some classes in CSS and play with addClass / removeClass on your elements instead of writing purely CSS in javascript !